# How do I mount partition to mount point with UUID? - mega noob

Tags: mount

Hi there noob here 1st post on this community.

I have created a partition on a windows shared hdd and created a mount point  but I don't understand the instructions online. Can you write exactly what I need to put in the terminal? I don't really know how to use it yet

Comment: Please link to the instructions that you do not understand

Comment: If you provide the actual 'instructions' online that you believe are unclear; we can read & see for ourselves & possibly *improve* them if you're talking about Ubuntu documentation (not if it's 3rd party or unofficial). Myself I'd use two commands, `blkid` to get the UUID, and then `vim` to edit modify my *fstab* (file system table), but `vi` isn't for newbies  (this is info that's in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions anyway, though it uses another way instead of `blkid`)